# How can i get all records from all tables using stored procedure in my sql

Tags: java, mysql

table A:-

```
  a_id(p_k) | data1 | data2 
    1         xxx      yyy
```

table B:-

```
  b_id(p_k) | bbb1 | bbb2  
    1         xxx     yyy
```

table C:-

```
   c_id |  cc1 | ccc2 |a_id (F_K-Table A)  | b_id (F_K-Table B) 
     1      xx   yy     1                      1
```

Question - I want such a stored proceduer to get all data from A, B ,C table which are                  present in  C table...

I have Java Entities for A, B, C...
 In C table i have used ManyToOne for A.
 In C table i have used ManyToOne for B.

Comment: do you wants to join the all table details like a b c

Answer (score 1):

try this: use the `inner join`

```
SELECT 
A.data1,A.data2,
B.bbb1,B.bbb2,
C.cc1,C.cc2
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN TABLE C
ON A.a_id =C.a_id 
INNER JOIN TABLE B
ON B.b_id=C.b_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JOIN

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.*
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableC C
ON A.a_id =C.a_id 
INNER JOIN tableB B
ON B.b_id=C.b_id
```